# Attribute Error with Python

Tags: python, syntax, attributes

I can't seem to figure out what is causing the below attribute error. I am really not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be great!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project2.py", line 140, in 
    movie_writter.writerow([movie.title, movie.author, movie.itunes_id, movie.itunes_URL, movie.length])
AttributeError: 'Movie' object has no attribute 'length'

```
class Movie(Media):
    def __init__(self, diction_file):
        Media.__init__(self, diction_file)
        self.rating = diction_file['contentAdvisoryRating']
        self.genre = diction_file['primaryGenreName']
        try:
            self.track_time = diction_file['trackTimeMillis']
        except:
            self.track_time = 0
        try:
            self.description = diction_file['longDescription']
        except:
            self.description = None

    def __len__(self):
        return self.track_time/1000
    def title_words_num(self):
        if self.description != None:
            return len(self.description.split())
        else:
            return 0

    movie_list = [Movie(diction_file) for diction_file in movie_samples]

    with open('movies.csv', 'w', newline = '') as movies_csv:
        movie_writter = csv.writer(movies_csv, delimiter=',')
        movie_writter.writerow(["Title", "Artist", "ID", "URL", "Length"])
        for movie in movie_list:
            movie_writter.writerow([movie.title, movie.author, movie.itunes_id, movie.itunes_URL, movie.length])
    movies_csv.close()
```

Comment: Can we see your movie object?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I just edited my post to show the movie object, thanks!

Comment: @roganjosh I added the Movie class that I created, thanks!

Comment: Why did you expect these objects to have a `length` attribute? You don't seem to have made one.

Comment: Ok, so what happens if you change `movie.length` to `len(movie)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means what it means: the object has no attribute `length`. You probably meant `len(movie)`, which maps to `__len__` magic method.

Also, keep in mind, this is not the best use for the `__len__` method. It is supposed to be used for collections/containers of any kind, to show the amout of items inside. The movie duration is not an amount of things.